# Looking for pograms on client machines

Tags: powershell

i got a client who wants to find all of the companys installed programs i wrote a script but i dont want the script show me the same same programs for each comuter every time,i want to see overall installations

```
  $computers = get-adcomputers -filter *
  foreach($computer in $computers){
  Get-ItemProperty 
  HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format- 
  Table –AutoSize}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but you can try

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).DNSHostName   # or use .Name or .CN

$software = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
                Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            }
$software | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate -Unique |
            Format-Table -AutoSize
```

<sup>P.S.1 You need to have admin permissions on all computers to do this</sup>

<sup>P.S.2 Don't forget there is also `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`</sup>

---

Apparently you are running into problems where computers are off-line.
To overcome that, you need to add a loop so you can test if a machine is reachable or not.

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name   # or use .CN

# loop through the collection and (if reachable) get the software list
$result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    # test if the computer is online
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # output the properties you need to get collected in variable $result
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        } | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $computer is off-line"
    }
}

$software = $result | Select-Object * -Unique

# output to console
$software | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$software | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Software.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: And what issue would that be? Please state the error messages in full

Comment: it says "cannot validate argument on parameter 'computername' the argument is null" i used your version of the script

Comment: i changed the first row from dnshostname to name and got a diferent error that says the Winrm client cannot process the request becoust the server name cannot be resolved

Comment: i tried another script that goes like this : Get-CimInstance -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\Temp\Computer.txt) -ClassName win32_product -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Select-Object PSComputerName, Name, PackageName, InstallDate | Out-GridView but i get an error for servers that are offline and im not sure the script is keep looking for more servers

Comment: @Lyoxa_grimm I have added new code to check if the computer is reachable before trying to get the software list